# Is it possible to upgrade log4j 1.2.8 to log4j 2.17 while using JBoss 4 and Java 1.4?

Tags: java, jboss, log4j2

On a legacy project tech stack using is, Java 1.4, JBoss 4, EJB 1.x, MS-SQL database server 13.x Enterprise version.

Is it possible to upgrade log4j 1.2.8 to log4j 2.17 without upgrading to Java 8 and JBoss latest version like 7.x?

Comment: No, you can't, given log4j2 2.17.x is Java 8 or higher (and 2.3.2 is Java 6 or higher, and 2.12.4 is Java 7 or higher). It is crazy that your company is still running something on Java 1.4, which was end-of-public-updates ***14 years** ago*. Updating Log4j is the least of your problems (as an aside, Log4j 1.x is a totally different product that Log4j2, it has different vulnerabilities).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so first we need to upgrade to Java 1.8 right, after searching online I got to know another complication which is JBoss 4 doesn't supports Java 1.8. Will it be very complicated to upgrade JBoss 4 to JBoss 7.x. Also we have EJB's in this application, EJB 1.1 is the EJB version, I realized that even EJB version need to upgraded in this case.

Comment: Yes, it is a lot of work. That's what you get when you ignore nearly two decades of updates and releases (e.g. Java 5 was released in 2004).